# Where to add class weights for imbalanced dateset using in TensorFlow Object Detection API, can I add in config file?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision, object-detection, loss-function

I am training EfficienDet D4 on my custom dataset using TensorFlow Object Detection API,
I have an imbalanced dataset so, I am planning to add class weights to give extra weightage for my classes which has lesser count. I got the concept but I am stuck with where to add this. Can I add this in pipeline config file?? If yes where?. Otherwise which is the file where model.fit lies. Please give suggestions. Or if there is better way of doing this, please let me know.
[where does class_weights or weighted loss penalize the network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65417379/where-does-class-weights-or-weighted-loss-penalize-the-network)
Actually I want to implement the solutions from the above link

Answer (score 0):

Imbalanced datasets is the imbalance of class samples that leads to over fits problem we usually handling this by the custom callback before they are using early callback. **( On specific usages )**

You can apply exponential decay** on the on_epoch_begin or using target number.

You can also apply weights back to target layers conditions for ratios.

**Weights applied:**

```
layer_2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, kernel_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.))
b_out =  layer_2(group_1_ShoryuKen_Left)
layer_2.set_weights(layer_1.get_weights())
```

**Callbacks:**

```
class custom_callback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    if ( logs['loss'] <= 0.4 ) :
        self.model.stop_training = True
            
    if(round(logs['loss'], 6) == round(logs['val_loss'], 6) and round(logs['loss'], 6) > 0 and round(logs['loss'], 6) == round(previous_loss_number, 6) and i_same_loss_number > 50):
        self.model.stop_training = True
                
    if(logs['accuracy'] >= 0.9 and logs['loss'] < 0.2 and int(epoch) == 5 ):
        self.model.stop_training = True

def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs={}):
    global globalstep
    globalstep = globalstep + 1
    previous_loss_number = self.previous_loss_number 
    i_same_loss_number = self.i_same_loss_number
    i_radious = self.i_radious
    lr = self.lr
        
    if not hasattr(self.model.optimizer, "lr"):
        raise ValueError('Optimizer must have a "lr" attribute.')

    if globalstep >  pow(10, i_radious) and ( history.history['loss'][len(history.history['loss']) - 1] == history.history['val_loss'][len(history.history['loss']) - 1] ) and ( history.history['loss'][len(history.history['loss']) - 1] == previous_loss_number ) and ( i_same_loss_number > 100 ) :
        i_radious = i_radious + 1

    lr = round(model.optimizer.lr.numpy(), i_radious)

    ################################################################
    scheduled_lr = self.scheduler(epoch, lr)
    # Set the value back to the optimizer before this epoch starts
    tf.keras.backend.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, scheduled_lr)
    print("\nEpoch %05d: Learning rate is %6.7f." % (epoch, scheduled_lr))

custom_callback = custom_callback()
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yue6H.jpg)